# How can I directly edit the PGP signature of a commit?

Tags: git

I'm trying to replicate git commits exactly (with exact matching SHAs) through git commands. I can record the PGP signature, but how could I insert the recorded signature onto a new commit without using gpg?

Here's the original commit that I'd like to replicate:

```
author s130 <author@users.noreply.github.com> 1559763035 -0800
committer GitHub <noreply@github.com> 1559763035 -0800
gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP+BhbCRBK7hj9Ov4rIwAAdHIIAHNl2VzESu4fShThzvvK6SV2
 IDnvDnh1aBlIL4acSGzwzegg0Ldkq1/eumYmXxNiRhQYn65UUA59AwMQzKkDostw
 b8lMXyqi/po1q1r6IK6dW3ES9F7hFVVwJuW0ga6XMVNyMhhDVD2KDROO8kx2bIU7
 i/Vv0vFHXFEc/Ui3UPQ+uIMFNJRB2ZbR4hDoHG92251Ba0rExEKmCc2cKEopoG9m
 OxYFEVKAIbJRAsXK29CsljqNrVaMy91vUEjdh5J9bxRLhiGFksMue2NUtk91cVge
 yWkwnStAU6qH8GFmjxT+7Uh674gkjIBsxVznnZsLBH18XvsRsmGSMAsMl3TmhK0=
 =AB0C
 -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----


Initial commit
```

And here's my attempt at replicating it:

```
author s130 <author@users.noreply.github.com> 1559763035 -0800
committer GitHub <noreply@github.com> 1559763035 -0800

Initial commit
```

The only difference is the lack of a gpgsig header. How can I manually add/edit it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want to ensure the SHAs of the original commit and the replicant commit are exactly the same. Since the gpgsig affects the SHA, I need some way to directly insert the signature

Comment: Are you also changing the content of the commits?

Comment: No. The idea is to perfectly replicate the commit somewhere else. I make identical changes to the identical files and set git environment variables to mirror the original author, committer, dates, etc. Currently the only thing I'm missing is the PGP signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can synthesize the object yourself and pass it to `git hash-object -w`, which will hash it and then write it into the database. You can then attach it to a reference (branch, tag, etc.) with `git update-ref`.

Git doesn't provide a way for you to create an object with an arbitrary signature other than you synthesizing the object yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, HOWEVER, with a GPG signature. Can somebody please help me with the process of preparing a synthetic commit, with a GPG signature attached? I am taking commit from HEAD, appending some string to the message, then replacing HEAD with it. *What I want is to somehow let `hash-object` also consider my signature so that the `$final_object` I received is already signed by my key. This is what I am executing `commit_object=$(git cat-file -p HEAD)` `&&` `final_object=$(echo "$commit_object $append_string" | git hash-object --stdin -t commit)` .Please help!

Comment: That's going to need to have a different answer, so go ahead and ask it as a new question.